# Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float error in Tensorflow 2.0. What's causing this?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

Conversion of image data error constantly prompted while following a tutorial. 
img.shape appears to be problematic too

I've checked that the file location is accurate, moved a single file over to examine the issue and now I'm completely stumped

```
# region Directory setting
dog_train_path = "./training_set/dogs/"
# endregion

# region Preparing and loading files
with zipfile2.ZipFile(train_file, 'r') as unzipped:
    unzipped.extractall()


def load_image(file_path):
    return cv2.imread(file_path)

def extract_numerical_label(file_name):
    return 1 if "dog" in file_name else 0


# region Load training labels and variables
image_files = os.listdir(dog_train_path)
train_images = [load_image(dog_train_path + file) for file in image_files]
train_labels = [extract_numerical_label(file) for file in image_files]


# region Preprocess data
def preprocess_image(img, side=96):
    plt.imshow(None)
    min_side = min(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])
    img = img[:min_side, :min_side]
    img = cv2.resize(img, (side, side))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return img / 255.0


# endregion

# region Test before and after images
preview_index = 1000
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(train_images[preview_index])
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(preprocess_image(train_images[preview_index]), cmap="gray")
# endregion
```

The error:

**File "C:\Users\directory\matplotlib\image.py", line 685, in set_data
    "float".format(self._A.dtype))
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be both due to an error in the directory I was reading from and due to an improper file being read from the dataset.

Be sure to double check your contents and directories!